# my assembly code is not running idk why already setup visual studios to run x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

my code is not running i am losing my mind idk whats happening the error that visual studios says is on the first line under main proc "mov edx, OFFSET msg1" is a main(void) atleast before it seems to work fine now but the code isnt giving me the right output can anyone help?

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc
includelib irvine32.lib

.data
    arabic DWORD 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1
roman BYTE "M\0\0", "CM\0", "D\0\0", "CD\0", "C\0\0", "XC\0", "L\0\0", "XL\0", "X\0\0", "IX\0", "V\0\0", "IV\0", "I\0\0"
    N DWORD 0
    msg1 BYTE 'Enter arabic number:', 0
    msg2 BYTE '\nRoman number:', 0

.code
main PROC
    ; Print msg1
    mov edx, OFFSET msg1
    call WriteString

    ; Read input into N
    call ReadInt
    mov DWORD PTR [N], eax

    ; Print msg2
    mov edx, OFFSET msg2
    call WriteString

    mov esi, 0

convert_loop:
    cmp esi, 12 
    jge exit_loop

    ; Compare N with arabic[i]
    mov eax, [arabic + esi * 4]
    cmp N, eax
    jl increment_index

    ; Print Roman numeral and update N
    movzx eax, [esi * 2 + roman]
    call WriteChar
    sub N, eax
    jmp convert_loop

increment_index:
    add esi, 1
    jmp convert_loop

exit_loop:
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP
END main
```

i was told my data section was incorrect and fixed it to what it is now not sure if that helped and i switched the move edx to PUSH but it made it worse so i switched it back not sure whatelse to do.
edit: kinda mentioned it but it runs fine theres no main(void) error but if its possible to tell me why it happened that would be great the only issue now is it doesnt give me the right roman numeral

Comment: `roman` is defined as an array of **3bytes** NULL-padded Roman digits. At `Print Roman numeral` it should be addressed `movzx eax, [esi + esi*2 + roman]`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> roman BYTE "M\0\0", "CM\0", "D\0\0", "CD\0", "C\0\0", "XC\0", "L\0\0", "XL\0", "X\0\0", "IX\0", "V\0\0", "IV\0", "I\0\0"
> ```

This is an array that has **13** zero-terminated strings each containing one **or two** displayable characters.

Focusing on where the action is:

> ```
>   mov esi, 0
> convert_loop:
>   cmp esi, 12 
>   jge exit_loop
>   ; Compare N with arabic[i]
>   mov eax, [arabic + esi * 4]
>   cmp N, eax
>   jl increment_index
>   ; Print Roman numeral and update N
>   movzx eax, [esi * 2 + roman]
>   call WriteChar
>   sub N, eax
>   jmp convert_loop
> increment_index:
>   add esi, 1
>   jmp convert_loop
> ```

- You are not using the 13th array elements.
- Your addressing of the *roman* array is out of sync because of 'times 2' instead of 'times 3'. See [vitsoft's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670435/my-assembly-code-is-not-running-idk-why-already-setup-visual-studios-to-run-x86#comment136931212_77670435).
- You read and write a single character and thus are leaving behind half of those 2-character strings
- You subtract from *N* a bogus value. What you subtract must come from the *arabic* array.

Next is a quick rewrite where you should take note that I have placed the loop condition at the bottom, shaving off the unconditional `jmp`:

```
  xor  esi, esi
convert_loop:
  mov  ebx, [arabic + esi * 4]      ; Compare N with arabic[i]
  cmp  N, ebx
  jb   increment_index
  lea  edx, [roman + esi + esi * 2] ; Print Roman numeral and update N
same_char:
  call WriteString                  ; It's a string, not just a char
  sub  N, ebx                       ; Subtract the arabic value
  cmp  N, ebx                       ; Could appear multiple times
  jnb  same_char
increment_index:
  inc  esi
  cmp  esi, 13                      ; Valid indexes are [0,12]
  jb   convert_loop
```

### Alternative solution

For when you're willing to modify the *roman* array so that it contains **4**-byte zero-terminated strings. You keep the *arabic* and *roman* arrays adjacent: separation is 52 bytes.

```
arabic DWORD 1000,      900,      500,       ...
roman  BYTE  "M\0\0\0", "CM\0\0", "D\0\0\0", ...

  ...

  mov  esi, OFFSET arabic
convert_loop:
  mov  ebx, [esi]      ; Compare N with arabic[i]
  cmp  N, ebx
  jb   increment_index
  lea  edx, [esi + 52] ; Print Roman numeral and update N
same_char:
  call WriteString     ; It's a string, not just a char
  sub  N, ebx          ; Subtract the arabic value
  cmp  N, ebx          ; Could appear multiple times
  jnb  same_char
increment_index:
  add  esi, 4
  cmp  esi, OFFSET roman
  jb   convert_loop
```